# How to iterate through all table pages with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, pagination

I am trying to view all pages from 1-50. However, I'm having trouble iterating through all the pages with `iselementpresent`.

The table pages:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

I tried to iterate through each one with

```
If iselementpresent(nextpagenumber) then
 click on nextPageNumber
else:
 print "done"
```

However, when `iselementpresent()` reaches page 12, it will say page 12 is NOT present, then gives me an error. Isn't `iselementpresent` supposed to help me avoid running into errors?

Comment: I assume your code is failing in click. Could be that link for 12 was present at the time if condition was executed and then there was a page load or something which caused the error in click. Also its better to use isVisible in this case. Because, element might be present in source but might be hidden.

Comment: Do you try to wait for page to load (also to finish AJAX if any) before clicking on next page number. Since it might be the case that if you don't wait for page load the next number link might not have rendered at the time of clicking.

Comment: You were right, my code was failing because the pages change from </a> to </span> after it went to the next set of pages. Thanks for you help!

Comment: you can try [splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info).

Answer (score 1):

basic idea is to wait all the AJAX returns to the page on switching on another table page.
try using a pair of methods: fluent wait + isElementDisplayed.

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                }
                }
);
                           return  foo;              }     ;
```

Select any web element that  is present on EVERY table page and wait for it with the fluent wait and then swich to next table page.
+ add additional check with

```
String cssSelector= ....
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).isDisplayed()
```

Hope this works for you)